# Determine if list is ascending, descending, or neither without built-ins

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I am trying to solve a problem

> Given a list of `n` terms check if the elements are in ascending,
>   descending, or neither without using `def` and
>   `inbuilt` functions.

Example inputs:

```
list1 = [1,2,3,4] # Output -> In list1 elements are arranged in ascending order.
list1 = [4,3,2,1] # Output -> In list1 elements are arranged in descending order.
list1 = [1,3,2,4] # Output -> In list1 the elements are not arranged in any order.
```

I could easily do it using  `list1.sort()` and `list1.sort(reverse=True)`

What I wrote...

```
list1 = [1,2,3,4]
if list1 == list1.sort():
     print('ascending')
elif list1 == list1.sort(reverse=True):
     print('descending')
else:
    print('not in order')
```

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please edit your question to include the code you've already written for your solutions attempts, as well as any errors you get from it. If you haven't written any code, go write some! StackOverflow is **not** a code-writing service; every asker is expected to have put at least *some* effort into trying to solve their issue, and *show* that effort *directly in the question*. Once you have provided your code along with a *specific* error or problem, we'd be happy to help :)

Comment: @Das_Geek I tried... And edited... Pls don't down vote

Comment: @Jayesh-B Please see my edit on how I formatted your question. Usually questions asking for help with homework are not well received on SO since professors put requirements on the problem which makes answers useless to real-world problems (Such as no `def` or `in-built`) and this is also supposed to be a learning opportunity for you (you learn nothing if we just give you an answer). That being said the wording of a problem is often scrutinized as well so get in the habit of properly formatting you question AND especially properly formatting the code you paste.

Comment: @Error-SyntacticalRemorse true sir they just give the question don't use inbuilt for all... I feel we must be allowed to do so so that we develop interest in python and feel like exploring the language

Comment: Well yeah... What u mean to say is that to code better I need to know how that function works by trying to code without it and the later when I grow up and start developing real world applications I use inbuilt functions as I already have understood what they do and my code becomes cleaner?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a possible solution:

```
ascending = True
descending = True
prev_index = 0
for index in range(1, len(list1)):
    ascending = ascending and list1[index] >= list1[prev_index]
    descending = descending and list1[index] <= list1[prev_index]
    prev_index = index

if ascending:
    print("Elements are arranged in ascending order")
elif descending:
    print("Elements are arranged in descending order")
else:
    print("Elements are not arranged in any order")
```

When all the elements of a list are equal (for example, `list1 = [1,1,1]`), both ascending and descending are `True`: in my solution the list is considered to be ascending.

Comment: Can I check if all values in list are equal it will tell the user all values were equal and ask them to input the list again...

Answer (score 0):

You could use a loop, like a for(conditions) and compare if the first element is less than the next one and so forth.

Here is a pseudo-code:

```
for(conditions)

if(element < next element)

keep going

if not then break and display
that the array is not arranged
```

**Note:** This will be for ascending order, for descending order will be similar by just changing the if(condition)

Comment: What is the condition

Comment: if(element ">" next element) because you want to make sure that the current element will be greater than the next elements and so forth.